# Custom Outline Problem

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, focus, outline

I made the following script to override the browsers' default outlining system:

```
*
{
  margin: 0;
  outline-color: #C79700;
  outline-width: 1px;
  padding: 0;
}

$('document').delegate('[tabindex]', 'focusin focusout mousedown', function(event)
{
    var target = $(event.target);

    switch(event.type)
    {
        case 'focusin':
        {
            var clicked = target.data('clicked');

            target.removeData('clicked');

            if (clicked)
                target.css('outline-style', 'none');
            else
                target.css('outline-style', 'solid');

            break;
        }

        case 'focusout':
            target.css('outline-style', 'none');
            break;

        case 'mousedown':
        {
            if (target.prop('tagName') === 'B')
                target = target.parent();

            if (!target.is(':focus'))
                target.data('clicked', true);
            else
                target.css('outline-style', 'none');

            break;
        }
    }
})
```

Everything works perfectly but I have a minor issue: if I activate another window (by minimizing the browser or using ALT+TAB), the document loses the focus and so does the element... then, if I reactivate the browser window, data('clicked') is obviously false and if a [tabindex] element is selected, it is outlined by the script.

How can I prevent this? I've tried a lot of solutions without success. Is there something like:

```
            if (clicked || browser-has-just-become-active)
                target.css('outline-style', 'none');
            else
                target.css('outline-style', 'solid');
```

Many many thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you can use:

```
window.onfocus
```

or for IE:

```
document.onfocusin
```